# Задать переходящий цвет буквам

Tags: html, css

### Подскажите как реализовать такой цвет букв с помощью *css.*

[image: 123]

Answer (score 4):

Могу предложить так(возможно, не все сочетания и комбинации цветов вижу):

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 72px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#e74c3c 49%, #c0392b 50%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
span{
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ff7675 49%, #c0392b 50%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<h1>В ЛЕ<span>ТО</span></h1>
```

Comment: В IE не работает( нужен кроссбраузерный способ

Comment: @RafaelShepard, Ну знаете, тут не фриланс, а помощь.

Comment: @Other чего вообще? зачем этот набор слов? я как раз за помощью и пишу, т.к. не знаю как такое реализовать.

Comment: @RafaelShepard вам намекают что дальнейшие действия вы можете загуглите самостоятельно

Answer (score 2):

Это геморой, но если включить фантазию то получится вот так

```css
span {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
}

.parent p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

p:first-child {
  color: red;
  z-index: 5;
}

p.blue {
  overflow: hidden;
  top: -20px;
  z-index: 10;
}

p:last-child span {
  display: block;
  color: blue;
  transform: translateY(20px);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <p><span>Hei man</span></p>
  <p class="blue"><span>Hei man</span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: прикольная идея с наложением)! спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Вот так кроссбраузерно(до IE9 включительно). По другому: либо дублирование текста(вариант Максима Ленского), либо картинкой. В общем, лёгких путей тут не будет.

```css
#resources {
  width:0;
  height:0;
  overflow:hidden;
}

button {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #fea857;
  border: 8px solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  border-color: #fedca2 #fec885 #db8646 #db8646;
  cursor:pointer;
}

button svg {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
}

button text {
  font-family:sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-anchor: middle;
  fill: url(#gradient);
}
```

```html
<svg id="resources">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0%" y1="0" x2="0%" y2="100%" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#f83618" />
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#ac1e12" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
</svg>

<button>
  <svg>    
    <text x="100" y="30">в лето</text>
  </svg>
</button>
```

Comment: Так. сейчас сяду разбираться) спасибо)